# Converting Long number to byte array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to convert a long number (convertex from Hex to Long) to a byte array. I'm trying the following code:

```
    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
    // The literal 4328719365 of type int is out of range 
    b.putLong(4328719365);
    byte[] result = b.array();
```

but it's not compiling due to being out of range for `int`.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: b.putLong(4328719365L); Note **L**. And keep in mind, that long takes 8 bytes :)

Comment: @kofemann Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferOverflowException

Comment: @Harold: Probably because a `long` needs 8 bytes and your buffer only has allocated 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suffix `L` (or `l`) converts literal number to a `long`.

So try this:

```
b.putLong(4328719365L);
```

You can use literal long value just like number without L suffix. Like assign them to variables:

```
long myLongValue = 4328719365L;
b.putLong(myLongValue);
```

Comment: Note that `L` is considered by some to be preferable, because `l` looks a lot like `1` in some fonts.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I put it with a variable name? Like b.putLong(longL);

Comment: @Harold you don't need to do it with a variable: you simply declare the variable as `long`. It's only literals where you need to use the `L`.

Answer (score 0):

1) Suffix L to the value
2) Increase the ByteBuffer allocated size and try
3) Int will take max of 10 digits and putLong might internally add L and making it beyond 10. Please check reducing digits in number.

Comment: `putLong` will not write a String representation in decimal digits. And definitely not add an `L` at. the end. It writes the raw binary value.